# Cubic Cycle is Np-Complete

Tags: algorithms

HAMCYCLE = {<"G"> : G is a simple undirected
graph that has a Hamiltonian cycle}

CUBIC CYCLE = {<"G"> :G is a simple undirected graph that contains
a simple cycle of length at least |V (G)|^1/3}

The reduction i figured out is :
G has a ham-cycle <==> G has a cubic cycle of a given length(V^1/3).
Prooving ==> part is simple as we have to show that if a cycle of V exists, then in G a cycle of V^1/3 exists.
But i got stuck in proving the other direction.
Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction that you suggested does not work. For example, consider a graph $G = (V, E)$ that consists of 9 disjoint triangles ( triangles that do not touch each other). $G$ has a triangle which a hamiltonian cycle of length $3 = 27^{\frac{1}{3}} = |V|^{\frac{1}{3}}$, yet $G$ has no hamiltonian cycle.

A simple correct reduction operates as follows. Given an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$, the reduction outputs $G$ with additional $|V|^3 - |V|$ isolated vertices. I leave the details to you.

Comment: Can we have a reduction for the connected graph also?

Comment: @Inuyashayagami I'm not sure I understand your question. The reduction I gave does not assume something about whether the input $G$ is connected.

Comment: I mean the following question: "Can we show that Cubic Cycle is NP-hard on connected graphs?"

Comment: Yes, good question. It can be shown that the problem is still hard. But the reduction is trickier. Assuming that Hamcycle is hard for  connected graphs: given a connected graph $G$, you can add to $G$ new vertices in a way that the graph remains connected yet the additional vertices do not introduce longer simple cycles. Hint: add "many" small cycles to $G$ that meet at the same vertex.

Comment: Thanks for attending my question. I did not get your hint. But I understand the idea. There can be many ways to do it. For example, we can simply add all the $|V|^{3} - |V|$ vertices as pendant vertices to any common vertex of $G$. This should also work.